# Prevent from adding active class to section on fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

When loading first section of *fullpage.js* page, it adds `active` class to the section. The problem is that class triggers animation behind the scene, so the user will see finished animation. How to prevent *fullpage.js* from adding `active` class to the section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fullpage.js event callback functions for this,

```
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){},
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
    afterRender: function(){},
    afterResize: function(){},
    afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){},
    afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){},
    onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex){}
```

see this documentation https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

when leaving the first slide add the callback function to the `onLeave:` to remove the active class from that element, like

```
$('.class').fullpage({
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
// remove the active class here
}
});
```

Comment: Ok, what about if I'm entering the first slide?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `afterLoad` callback. please check this website, http://gesturelang.ru/fullPage.js-master_/examples/callbacks.html#firstPage , there you can see the working of each callbacks while sliding. @yuriy N